# Tab-model 4th child not being displayed

Tags: html, css

I am working on this tab-model and got some issue with it. I was just going through the tab-models and found this interesting. But what I found is only three tabs. So, as far as I know, I've added the code for the fourth tab but It is not being displayed. There is some miscalculation with the rotation.

```css
.perspective {
  perspective: 76em;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50px;
  width: 494px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 47px;
  background: pink;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 47px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tab:nth-child(1) {
  top: -5px;
  background: #06d6a0;
}

.tab:nth-child(2) {
  top: 53px;
  background: #1b9aaa;
}

.tab:nth-child(3) {
  top: 112px;
  background: #ef476f;
}

.tab:nth-child(4) {
  top: 170px;
  background: GREEN;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: 0 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.tab-content h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 75px 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-content p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: #06d6a0;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  background: #1b9aaa;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(100px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  background: #ef476f;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateX(25deg) translateY(-20px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  background: #9f476f;
}

#tab-top:checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

#tab-front:checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

#tab-bottom:checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

#tab-back:checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h4>Standard Accordion with A little styling</h4>

<div class="perspective">

  <label class="tab" for="tab-top">TOP</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-front">FRONT</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-bottom">BOTTOM</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-bottom">BACK</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-top">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-front">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-bottom">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-back">

  <div class="cube">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>TOP CONTENT</h1>
      <p>THIS IS AWESOME</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>FRONT CONTENT</h1>
      <p>THIS IS COOL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>BOTTOM CONTENT</h1>
      <p>THIS IS SWEET</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>BACK CONTENT</h1>
      <p>THIS IS SPECTACULAR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change

```
<label class="tab" for="tab-bottom">BACK</label>
```

to

```
<label class="tab" for="tab-back">BACK</label>
```

You have duplicated the `tab-bottom` label.

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8mr785t/1/) for a fully working example.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem with the rotation.

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan I have updated my answer with a fiddle link where you can find a fully working example.

Comment: can you help me out with the text mirroring?

Comment: Did you try something out for text mirroring please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to change the class for last item.

Now:

```
<label class="tab" for="tab-bottom">BACK</label>
```

And It should be:

```
<label class="tab" for="tab-back">BACK</label>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I missed that but the rotation is not working